# mantine Menu.dropdown not working I have paste same code from their Website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, mantine

I am watching a tutorial in which he used mantine Menu, so inside it he used Menu.Dropdown in which he add some items which works fine in his video, but now when I am working on it I got error and it tells me to wrap my React App inside the MantineProvider although in tutorial he didn't do that, but after doing this all stuff still my Dropdown is not working, and I try the template also which is on the website of mantine it's also not working, any idea why it's not woking so please let me know.

here's my code:

```
    import React from 'react'
import {Menu, Avatar} from "@mantine/core"
const ProfileMenu = ({logout, user}) => {
  return (
    <>
    <Menu>
        <Menu.Target>
            <Avatar src={user?.picture} alt='image' radius="xl"/>
        </Menu.Target>
        <Menu.Dropdown>
            <Menu.Item>Favourite</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>Logout</Menu.Item>
        </Menu.Dropdown>
    </Menu>
    </>
  )
}

export default ProfileMenu
```

mantine Menu template code:

```
import { Menu, Button, Text, rem } from '@mantine/core';
import {
  IconSettings,
  IconSearch,
  IconPhoto,
  IconMessageCircle,
  IconTrash,
  IconArrowsLeftRight,
} from '@tabler/icons-react';

function ProfileMenu() {
  return (
    <Menu shadow="md" width={200}>
      <Menu.Target>
        <Button>Toggle menu</Button>
      </Menu.Target>

      <Menu.Dropdown>
        <Menu.Label>Application</Menu.Label>
        <Menu.Item leftSection={<IconSettings style={{ width: rem(14), height: rem(14) }} />}>
          Settings
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item leftSection={<IconMessageCircle style={{ width: rem(14), height: rem(14) }} />}>
          Messages
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item leftSection={<IconPhoto style={{ width: rem(14), height: rem(14) }} />}>
          Gallery
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item
          leftSection={<IconSearch style={{ width: rem(14), height: rem(14) }} />}
          rightSection={
            <Text size="xs" c="dimmed">
              ⌘K
            </Text>
          }
        >
          Search
        </Menu.Item>

        <Menu.Divider />

        <Menu.Label>Danger zone</Menu.Label>
        <Menu.Item
          leftSection={<IconArrowsLeftRight style={{ width: rem(14), height: rem(14) }} />}
        >
          Transfer my data
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item
          color="red"
          leftSection={<IconTrash style={{ width: rem(14), height: rem(14) }} />}
        >
          Delete my account
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu.Dropdown>
    </Menu>
  );
}
export default ProfileMenu
```

both are not working .

Answer (score 1):

it's not working because I didn't import its CSS file

Just add:

```
import '@mantine/core/styles.css';
```